# logrotate seems to be working but does not rotate a log file

Tags: linux, logrotate

Here is my logs directory:

```
root@my-server:/var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs# ll
total 1468016
-rw-r--r-- 1 my-website webuser        95719295 Mar 19 18:04 my-website-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 my-website webuser        21130452 Apr 27  2019 my-website-access.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 my-website webuser          831892 Mar 17 15:39 my-website-error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root         1238469639 Mar 19 18:04 my-website-ssl-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root                 20 Mar 19 17:55 my-website-ssl-access.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root           16976113 Mar  2  2019 my-website-ssl-access.log.9.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root          102746845 Mar 19 18:04 my-website-ssl-error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 my-website webuser        21089307 Mar 19 18:03 test.my-website-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 my-website webuser         6243491 Mar 17 18:48 test.my-website-error.log
```

Note the massive > 1GB file sitting there. Here is my logrotate config file:

```
/var/www/vhosts/*/logs/*.log {
  rotate 8
  daily
  size 256M
  compress
  delaycompress
  sharedscripts

  postrotate
    /bin/systemctl reload apache2  > /dev/null
  endscript
}
```

When I run the command:

```
logrotate -vv -f /etc/logrotate.d/vhost
```

it appears to be working, I get these messages (amongst a lot of other noise):

```
considering log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log
  log needs rotating
...
rotating log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log, log->rotateCount is 8
dateext suffix '-20200319'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.1 does not exist
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.8.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.9.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 8), 
old log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.8.gz does not exist
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.7.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.8.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 7), 
old log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.7.gz does not exist
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.6.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.7.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 6), 
old log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.6.gz does not exist
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.5.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.6.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.5.gz does not exist
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.4.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.5.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.4.gz does not exist
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.3.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.4.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.3.gz does not exist
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.2.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.3.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.1.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.2.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.1.gz does not exist
renaming /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.0.gz to /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.1.gz (rotatecount 8, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.0.gz does not exist
log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-access.log.9.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
rotating log /var/www/vhosts/my-website/logs/my-website-ssl-error.log, log->rotateCount is 8
dateext suffix '-20200319'
```

...but the large log file does not appear to be being rotated despite logrotate apparently saying it has:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root         1238469639 Mar 19 18:04 my-website-ssl-access.log
```

Any idea what this would be happening?